# table print in the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var htmlStart =
                '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
                '<html>' +
                '<head>' +
                '<meta charset="utf-8" />'
                '</head>' +
                '<body>';
var title = '<header><h1>' + 'MyTitle' + '</h1></header>';

var printableContent =  "<table cellpadding='2'><tr><td> ....</td></tr></table>";

var htmlEnd= '</body>' + '</html>';

var fullcontent = htmlStart + title + printableContent + htmlEnd;
        doc.write(fullcontent);
        doc.close();
        win.print();
```

Here, my problem is, title is printed in first page and the tabel is printed in second page. I want both content in same page. Any solution??. Thanks..!

Comment: What do you mean first and second page? I don't see any pages...

Comment: @Mattew Herbst. Yeah, Second page means that table content start with new page. Only the title print in the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this via CSS:**

```
@media print {
    table {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

Comment: change this to `<header>` in your case.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using like this `table { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-before:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }`, its working fine...!